# Two pairs of TCP server/client sharing same code, but only one client receives messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

I have two pairs of simple TCP server/client, i.e., one client per server, running on Windows:

- Servers run in a process (app).
- Clients run in the other process.
- Servers keep sending heartbeats (a string) to their paired client.
- The first pair of server/client run their mainloops in their own threads.
- Once the first server/client have shaken hands with the first heartbeat, the second pair of server/client start their mainloops in their own threads.
- For this test, they run on the same machine with different ports: 2345 and 2346.

## Now my problem

- The first client receives its server's heartbeat.
- The second **client** does **NOT**, although the second **server** sent out heartbeats without errors.

Here is the server code:

```cpp
// hello_dualchannel_server.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. 

#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>


#define SPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT
#ifdef _DEBUG
#if !defined(SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL)
#define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL SPDLOG_LEVEL_TRACE
#endif  // #if !defined(SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL)
#define SPDLOG_DEBUG_ON
#define SPDLOG_TRACE_ON
#define _trace SPDLOG_TRACE 
#endif  // #ifdef _DEBUG
using namespace spdlog;

SOCKET g_sockFirst = 0;
SOCKET g_sockClientFirst = 0;
std::thread g_threadFirst;
uint32_t g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst = 0;

SOCKET g_sockSecond = 0;
SOCKET g_sockClientSecond = 0;
std::thread g_threadSecond;
uint32_t g_timeLatestHeartBeatSecond = 0;

void SetupLogger() {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S%z][%^%L%$][%t:%s:%#] %v");
#else
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::info);
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S][%^%L%$][%t] %v");
#endif  // #ifdef _DEBUG
}

int InitWinSock() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Confirm that the WinSock DLL supports 2.2.*/
    /* Note that if the DLL supports versions greater    */
    /* than 2.2 in addition to 2.2, it will still return */
    /* 2.2 in wVersion since that is the version we      */
    /* requested.                                        */

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
    return 0;
}

bool Init(int host_port, SOCKET* p_sockServer, SOCKET*p_sockClient) {
    int err = 0;
    int* p_int = 0;
    std::string host_name("127.0.0.1");
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int addr_size = 0;
    sockaddr_in sadr_client;

    if (!*p_sockServer) {
        *p_sockServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (*p_sockServer == -1) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Server Error initializing socket: {}", log);
            goto FINISH;
        }

        p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p_int = 1;
        if ((setsockopt(*p_sockServer, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)
            || (setsockopt(*p_sockServer, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Server Error setting options: {}", log);
            free(p_int);
            goto FINISH;
        }
        free(p_int);
        info("Server socket is set up.");

        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);
        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(*p_sockServer, (sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Server Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port: {}", log);
            goto FINISH;
        }
        if (listen(*p_sockServer, 10) == -1) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Server Error listening: {}", log);
            goto FINISH;
        }
        info("SUCCESS: Server socket listening ...");
    }

    info("Server accepting connection ...");
    addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    char sAddress[MAX_PATH];
    *p_sockClient = accept(*p_sockServer, (sockaddr*)&sadr_client, &addr_size);
    if (*p_sockClient == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        char log[MAX_PATH];
        strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
        error("Server error accepting client connection: {}", log);
        // DO NOT close sockets here.
        return false;
    }
    inet_ntop(sadr_client.sin_family, &sadr_client.sin_addr, sAddress, MAX_PATH);
    g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst = GetCurrentTime();
    info("SUCCESS: Server accepted client connection.");
    return true;
FINISH:
    closesocket(*p_sockServer);
    return false;
}

bool IsConnected(uint32_t timeLatestHeartBeat) {
    // CAUTION: denser than client for sure catch
    const unsigned long ConnTimeoutMs = 300;
    auto cur = GetCurrentTime();
    auto latest = timeLatestHeartBeat;
    return cur - latest < ConnTimeoutMs;
}

bool StayInTouch(const char* name, SOCKET* pSockClient, uint32_t* pTimeLatestHeartBeat) {
    if (IsConnected(*pTimeLatestHeartBeat))
        return true;
    char heartBeat[] = "biku";
    int nBytesSent = 0;
    int flags = 0;
    int res = send(*pSockClient, heartBeat, sizeof(heartBeat), flags);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        char log[MAX_PATH];
        strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
        error("{}: Server failed to send heartbeat: {}, Windows error: {}", name, log, GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    else if (res == 0) {
        char log[MAX_PATH];
        strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
        error("{}: Server sent zerobyte heartbeat: {}", name, log);
        return false;
    }
    debug("{}: Heartbeat sent: {}", name, heartBeat);
    *pTimeLatestHeartBeat = GetCurrentTime();
    return true;
}

void Close(SOCKET* pSock) {
    closesocket(*pSock);
    *pSock = 0;
}

bool Connect() {
    if (g_threadFirst.joinable()) {
        warn("FirstTunnel already running. Skipped.");
        return true;
    }
    g_threadFirst = std::thread([&]() {
        bool isConnected = false;
        while (true) {
            while (!isConnected) {
                isConnected = Init(2345, &g_sockFirst, &g_sockClientFirst);
            }
            isConnected = StayInTouch("FirstTunnel", &g_sockClientFirst, &g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst);
            if (!isConnected) {
                // We don't close as client.
                // We keep connecting               
                error("About to reconnect ...");
                Sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }
            if (!g_threadSecond.joinable()) {
                g_threadSecond = std::thread([&]() {
                    while (true) {
                        while (!isConnected) {
                            isConnected = Init(2346, &g_sockSecond, &g_sockClientSecond);
                        }
                        isConnected = StayInTouch("SecondTunnel", &g_sockClientSecond, &g_timeLatestHeartBeatSecond);
                        if (!isConnected) {
                            // We don't close as client.
                            // We keep connecting               
                            error("About to reconnect ...");
                            Sleep(1000);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    info("SecondTunnel quitting...");
                    Close(&g_sockSecond);
                });
            }
        }
        info("FirstTunnel quitting...");
        Close(&g_sockFirst);
    });

    while (true) {
        //info("main thread ...");
        Sleep(3000);
    }

    return g_threadFirst.joinable() ? true : false;
}


int main() {
    SetupLogger();
    info("Hello World!\n");

    if (InitWinSock()) {
        critical("Failed to initialize Window socket. Aborted.");
    }

    Connect();

    if (g_threadSecond.joinable()) {
        g_threadSecond.join();
    }
    if (g_threadFirst.joinable()) {
        g_threadFirst.join();
    }
    WSACleanup();
    info("Bye!");
}
```

Here is the client code

```cpp
// hello_dualchannel_client.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. 
//

#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>

#define SPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT
#ifdef _DEBUG
#if !defined(SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL)
#define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL SPDLOG_LEVEL_TRACE
#endif  // #if !defined(SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL)
#define SPDLOG_DEBUG_ON
#define SPDLOG_TRACE_ON
#define _trace SPDLOG_TRACE 
#endif  // #ifdef _DEBUG
using namespace spdlog;

SOCKET g_sockFirst = 0;
std::thread g_threadFirst;
uint32_t g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst;

SOCKET g_sockSecond = 0;
std::thread g_threadSecond;
uint32_t g_timeLatestHeartBeatSecond;

void SetupLogger() {
#ifdef _DEBUG
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::trace);
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S%z][%^%L%$][%t:%s:%#] %v");
#else
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::info);
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S][%^%L%$][%t] %v");
#endif  // #ifdef _DEBUG
}

int InitWinSock() {
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Confirm that the WinSock DLL supports 2.2.*/
    /* Note that if the DLL supports versions greater    */
    /* than 2.2 in addition to 2.2, it will still return */
    /* 2.2 in wVersion since that is the version we      */
    /* requested.                                        */

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
        /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
        printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");
    return 0;
}

bool Init(int host_port, SOCKET* p_sock) {
    int err = 0;
    int* p_int = 0;
    std::string host_name("127.0.0.1");
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    char handshake[] = "hello";
    //int nBytesSent;
    if (!*p_sock) {
        *p_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (*p_sock == -1) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Client Error initializing socket {}", log);
            goto FINISH;
        }

        p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p_int = 1;
        if ((setsockopt(*p_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)
            || (setsockopt(*p_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1)) {
            char log[MAX_PATH];
            strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
            error("Client Error setting options {}", log);
            free(p_int);
            goto FINISH;
        }
        free(p_int);
        info("SUCCESS: Client socket is set up.");
    }

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);
    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    inet_pton(my_addr.sin_family, host_name.c_str(), &my_addr.sin_addr);
    if (connect(*p_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        char log[MAX_PATH];
        strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
        error("Client Error connecting socket {}", log);
        Sleep(1000);
        goto FINISH;
    }
    /*nBytesSent = send(g_sockFirst, handshake, sizeof(handshake), 0);
    if (nBytesSent <= 0) {
        char log[MAX_PATH];
        strerror_s(log, MAX_PATH, errno);
        error("Client error sending handshake: {}", log);
        goto FINISH;
    }*/
    g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst = GetCurrentTime();
    info("SUCCESS: Client connected to server.");
    return true;
FINISH:
    closesocket(*p_sock);
    *p_sock = 0;
    return false;
}

bool IsConnected(uint32_t timeLatestHeartBeat) {
    const unsigned long ConnTimeoutMs = 3000;
    auto cur = GetCurrentTime();
    auto latest = timeLatestHeartBeat;
    //if (cur - latest > ConnTimeoutMs)
    //{
    //  debug("cur: {}, late: {}", cur, latest);
    //} 
    return cur - latest < ConnTimeoutMs;
}

bool StayInTouch(const char* name, SOCKET* pSock, uint32_t* pTimeLatestHeartBeat) {
    // Client checks inbox right away and measure timeout later.
    char heartBeat[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    // CAUTION: min 100ms required for receiving heartbeat.
    //const uint32_t TimeoutMS = 100;
    int flags = 0;
    int nBytesRecved = recv(*pSock, heartBeat, sizeof(heartBeat), flags);
    bool gotHeartbeat = nBytesRecved > 0;
    if (gotHeartbeat) {
        debug("{}: Heartbeat received: {}", name, heartBeat);
        *pTimeLatestHeartBeat = GetCurrentTime();
    }
    return IsConnected(*pTimeLatestHeartBeat);
}

void Close(SOCKET* pSock) {
    closesocket(*pSock);
    *pSock = 0;
}

bool Connect() {
    if (g_threadFirst.joinable()) {
        warn("FirstTunnel already running. Skipped.");
        return true;
    }
    g_threadFirst = std::thread([&]() {
        bool isConnected = false;
        while (true) {
            while (!isConnected) {
                isConnected = Init(2345, &g_sockFirst);
            }
            isConnected = StayInTouch("FirstTunnel", &g_sockFirst, &g_timeLatestHeartBeatFirst);
            if (!isConnected) {
                // We don't close as client.
                // We keep connecting
                Close(&g_sockFirst);
                error("About to reconnect ...");
                continue;
            }
            if (!g_threadSecond.joinable()) {
                g_threadSecond = std::thread([&]() {
                    while (true) {
                        while (!isConnected) {
                            isConnected = Init(2346, &g_sockSecond);
                        }
                        isConnected = StayInTouch("SecondTunnel", &g_sockSecond, &g_timeLatestHeartBeatSecond);
                        if (!isConnected) {
                            // We don't close as client.
                            // We keep connecting               
                            error("About to reconnect ...");
                            Sleep(1000);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    info("SecondTunnel quitting...");
                    Close(&g_sockSecond);
                });
            }
        }
        info("FirstTunnel quitting.");
        Close(&g_sockFirst);
    });

    while (true) {
        //info("main thread ...");
        Sleep(3000);
    }

    return g_threadFirst.joinable() ? true : false;
}

int main() {
    SetupLogger();
    info("Hello World!\n");

    if (InitWinSock()) {
        critical("Failed to initialize Window socket. Aborted.");
    }

    Connect();

    if (g_threadSecond.joinable()) {
        g_threadSecond.join();
    }
    if (g_threadFirst.joinable()) {
        g_threadFirst.join();
    }
    WSACleanup();
    info("Bye!");
}
```

The main connection logic is in the function `Connect()`.
I'd appreciate tips on where I was wrong.

To run the code as is, you need one dependency `spdlog`

```
vcpkg install spdlog:x64-Windows
```

You can also replace all the spdlog-based logging code with your own.

## UPDATE

### Observation #1

I stepped into the code and confirmed

- All the loops are running. So all the threads are spawned.
- No redundant threads are spawned due to the `joinable()` guard.
- The only failure point is the `recv` call of the second client.

So conclusion

- No firewalls
- No redundant threads
- Both threads run on the client and server sides by design.

### Observation #2

While running the server and client programs and having let the problem happen, I tried

- Keep both programs open.
- Run netcat (NMap's `netcat` port) like this `C:\Apps\Nmap\ncat.exe 127.0.0.1 2346`

This actually help fix things. It tells me that there is a connection problem, while I could definitely step into the client code and see that the connection is still there.

### Observation #3

- After I leave breakpoints in only the second connection code of the client program, and run the program, I could not step out into the first connection code. Note that they are in separate threads.
- Leaving breakpoints in both connections, and quickly step over between them, I could keep the stepping going without getting trapped in only one thread. **This is when I notice that the client starts receiving the messages it should.**

So I suspect that there is a threading issue there. If that's the problem, How to fix this then?

Comment: Since it works on one setup the obvious culprit is a firewall. Have you checked that the client actually has an open connection to the server? Are they running on diifferent machines? Or the same with different ports?

Comment: @fredrik I just updated the question: yes they are on the same machine with two different ports.

Comment: And did you check that there actually is an open connection? No firewall running?

Comment: @fredrik Yes, no firewall. Both connections are open.

Comment: Oh, I see a problem now. Your first thread loop is going to be creating a new second thread every time it runs. This reinitializing the second thread.

Comment: @fredrik note that the second thread will be joinable and the guard will avoid creating new threads, right?

Comment: If it ever was not joinable - it's also completely plausible that it never goes into that part of the code

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Funny thing: I just tried to run `netcat` with `$ C:\Apps\Nmap\ncat.exe 127.0.0.1 2346`. This actually fixed the problem. But how??

Comment: I suspect that there is a threading issue: one thread grabbing CPU so the second thread cannot receive messages properly. Because as I setting breakpoints, I can't freely step into both threads with Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem myself. It was a stupid bug on my part:

The two threads share a state by mistake: `isConnected`. So the original programs keep kicking each other after one of them gains a new connection or heartbeat. They should have used different states for that.

To give more detail: `isConnected`, which is initialized by `g_threadFirst`, falls through the closure of `g_threadSecond`'s anonymous function.

Comment: @user207421 Yes it is in the code posted. See my updated answer. Please cancel your downvote when you see it, OK? Thanks for going through the code!